# cp: what quotation marks are used in error messages?

Tags: character-encoding, unicode

I'm currently fiddling around with a dying harddisk, and while trying to `cp` data from it, I get errors like

```
cp: error reading ‘brokenFile’: Input/output error
# comparison: backtick: `, apostrophe '
```

I now try to copy the failed files again by using `sed` to convert the error messages to new `cp` invocations (I was successfull some times already). But: what are the funny quotation marks? They are even different at start/end. It is no backtick and no apostrophe. I copy/pasted it into my regex, but is there a better way? Maybe using compose?

Comment: It probably generates some Unicode characters for English quotes. You should get error messages more friendly to `sed` (and automated processing in general) if you set the environment variable `LANG` to `C`.

Comment: They appear to be either wide or unicode characters. This is what i get when I try to put them in my terminal.

`
▒~@~Y
▒~@~X
`

Comment: OK, I now searched for them in the character map. They are `U+2018 LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK` and `U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK`.

Comment: @celtschk LANG=C works like a charm. I usually have en_US.utf8.

Comment: ... and sice I asked for compose key usage: the german wikipedia says Comp+<+' for left and Comp+>+' for right quotation mark. @celtschk do you want to write that up as an answer?

Comment: @Jasper: OK, done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The characters generated are `U+2018 LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK` (`‘`) and `U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK` (`’`). Those are typographical single quotes for the English language, and are generated because of your current locale. If your current keyboard layout has a compose key, you can enter them with <kbd>Compose</kbd><kbd><</kbd><kbd>'</kbd> (left quote) and <kbd>Compose</kbd><kbd>></kbd><kbd>'</kbd> (right quote).

However, if you want to process the output of a command with other tools (like, in your case, `sed`), it is usually easier to change the local by setting the environment variable `LANG` to `C`. That way, programs will output error messages (and more generally, all output meant to be human-readable) in pure ASCII, which is generally more easily handled using text-based tools.

Comment: You can set the locale "locally" to each command by just adding "LC_ALL=C" in front of the command itself. ex: `LC_ALL=C cp something somewhere` . Only cp here will have that locale forced. BUT don't forget to add similar forcing to any interpreting commands as well (sed, etc).  [otherwise things like `[A-Z]` ranges may turn out to be `all letters except 'a'`, for example... read for example http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Ranges-and-Locales.html . Added bonus : limiting to C range makes ranges faster, as containing far less characters in them than their unicode counterparts)

Answer (score 5):

A useful command to find out about a given character is Free recode (formerly known as GNU recode):

```
$ echo -n ‘’ | recode ..dump
UCS2   Mne   Description

2018   '6    left single quotation mark
2019   '9    right single quotation mark
```

Or the `unicode` command [from Debian](https://packages.debian.org/unstable/utils/unicode):

```
$ unicode ‘’
U+2018 LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK
UTF-8: e2 80 98  UTF-16BE: 2018  Decimal: &#8216;
‘
Category: Pi (Punctuation, Initial quote)
Bidi: ON (Other Neutrals)

U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK
UTF-8: e2 80 99  UTF-16BE: 2019  Decimal: &#8217;
’
Category: Pf (Punctuation, Final quote)
Bidi: ON (Other Neutrals)
```

Comment: I get from `echo -n ‘ | recode ..dump` the following: `1820         lettre mongole a` ...

Comment: @Jasper, on what system? I can't really see how the 18 and 20 could be revered. What's the output of `locale charmap` for you? Do you get the same with `recode u8..dump`?

Comment: `locale charmap` --> `UTF-8`. Same output with `u8..dump`. I'm running ArchLinux.

Comment: on an x86_64 CPU. I didn't realize until now that my numbers are just swapped... endianness-issue?!